# How much of the Game of Thrones show dialogue is taken directly from the books?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I'm currently re-watching the series (never read the books). Whenever there's a scene with Tyrion I always find myself impressed by the writing/his witty comebacks. Are these all the work of George, or did the show writers help out.

Comment: Are looking for all dialogue or just Tyrion's? Do you direct, absolute lines lifted directly from the books, or will "close enough" lines work? Either way that is quite broad, there are a lot words in both series...

Comment: Really not seeing how this is a duplicate - the other question shows the writers *can* change dialogue etc as much as they want, but this is a separate and interesting question about how much dialogue *is* straight from the books. Maybe it's too broad and would be better focused on only Tyrion's dialogue then reopened?